# Setup pyodbc connection without password in the connection string

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to set up pyodbc connection using only the DSN name in the connection string (primary goal is to NOT have the password in the connection string) like so:

```py
import pyodbc
cxxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=HARSHIT_CON")
```

Here is my `.odbc.ini` file:

```ini
[HARSHIT_CON]
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.1
Description=python
Database=my_db
Server=someserver,2500
user=harshitjindal
password=penguincontrolgroup
QuotedId=Yes
AnsiNPW=Yes
```

---

**Expected result**: for the connection to be setup because the username and password are defined in the `.odbc.ini` file, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hjind1/testdb.py", line 2, in <module>
    cxxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=HARSHIT_CON")
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

---

**What I have tried so far:**

1. To check if the correct `.odbc.ini` file is being read, I tried removing the `.odbc.ini` file, and the traceback shows that the DSN was not found. This leads me to believe the ini file is being read.
2. I noticed that the error says `Login failed for user ''.`. I thought that the user_id is not being detected, so I added the following lines to the ini file (hoping `UID` instead of `user` and `PWD` instead of `password` might help):

```
UID=harshitjindal
PWD=penguincontrolgroup
```

3. To try and solve the issue of user not being detected, I also tried to manually pass it in the connection string like so: `cxxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=HARSHIT_CON;UID=harshitjindal")`. This time the error message shows that the user is `harshitjindal` but connection failed. If I also pass the password in the connection string like `cxxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=HARSHIT_CON;UID=harshitjindal;PWD=penguincontrolgroup")`, then it works, but the entire idea is to remove the password from the connection string when it's already defined in the ini file.

How can I setup my connection without explicitely passing in the password (read it from the DSN config)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to realise that the `.odbc.ini` file needs to be treated like a config file. This was not intuitive because other parameters such as `Driver`, `Server`, `Database` were being read from the ini file *implicitly* upon calling `pyodbc.connect()`, but `user` and `password` (or `UID` and `PWD`) need to be read *explicitly*.

This can be done as follows:

```py
import pyodbc
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read("/Users/harshitjindal/.odbc.ini")   # odbc file path
DSN = "HARSHIT_CON"
cxxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN={0};UID={1};PWD={2}".format(DSN, config.get(DSN, "user"), config.get(DSN, "password")))
```